# CNN Feature Extraction Time

Tags: python, keras, convolution

I have a dataset consist of 260 thousands images that are extracted from several videos. I want to extract features of these images and use them for frame retrieval. I used VGG16 (pretrained on imagenet) that implemented in Keras library with 'avg' pooling in the last convolutional layer. VGG16 gives me a vector consist of 512 number (feature) for each image. The only reason that bothers me is that this scenario is too time-consuming. For my dataset, it took about a day and 6 hours which is too much.
Is this elapsed time normal?
Because of low performance, I switch from VGG16 to DenseNet121 that already implemented in Keras. For this model (now) it took a day and 18 hours to extract features from 33% of my images (about 86000).
I ask again: **Is this elapsed time normal?** 
 Is there any way to extract feature faster? Even without using of implemented algorithms?

 If you need more clarification, just ask for it. Thank You!

Comment: The speed depends on your hardware. Are you using a good gpu?

Comment: Nah, I'm using CPU :| I have Nvidia 740 GT, is it a good GPU? absolutely not :/ but can I use it anyway?